# How to style <apex:detail> element when page is rendered as pdf?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, stylesheets

I need to render pdf page with content from object. To do so I put `<apex:detail>` element in page and it is working, but its showing other elements from page layout that I don't need in pdf. I tried to apply styles, but I noticed that they working only if I indicate class explicitly.
For example:

```
.pbSubheader {
    display: none;
}
```

this style will hide all elements with class .pbSubheader, but if I won't to hide elements with more complicated logic then this styles are ignored, for example:

```
.pbBody .pbSubsection:not(:last-child) {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

this style will not work. How can I achive this?

Comment: Add an "id" to your tag and use CSS selectors when applying your style.

Comment: We don't have access to what `<apex:detail>` will generate

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set some variable to true, only when you render it as pdf, and use that variable in **rendered** attribute of those elements which you want to hide.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it. We don't have access to what `<apex:detail>` will generate.

Comment: Ohkk.. then instead of only main class, you will need to check exact hierarchy of classes being used on those elements which you want hide. (Parent to child elements)

Comment: But I need to use additional conditions like :last-child, :first-child

Comment: @user2452483 the css selectors you are using like :first-child and :last-child are from css3 and salesforce pdf engine does not support css3. So you should come up with css2.1 selectors for the elements you are trying to hide.